# Show mouseover text at certain width

Tags: html, css

I got an `<a>` tag, that has text inside of it.
On a phone screen the text is too long, so I hide it at a certain width.
When it's hidden I want to activate a mouseover text instead.
I tried it with `<a title="...">` but that mouseover-text stays visible when the screen is wide enough for the regular text.

**How can I disable that mouseover text at a certain screen-width?**
Or: **Any better alternatives to have a mouseover-text that hides at a certain width?**

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #changePw {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .fa {
    font-size: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="changePw" href="#" title="Change Password">
  <i class="fa">Icon</i> Change Password
</a>
```

Comment: could you make this a code snippet so we can see it - I don't understand why you would want to hide it and display the title instead on a mobile

Comment: @YvonneAburrow I made a code snippet!

Comment: thank you! I can work with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so I think what I would do is use a pseudo-class:

```css
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  #changePw {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  #changePw:hover:after  {
    content: "Change Password";
    padding: 4px 8px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 5em;
  }
  .fa {
    font-size: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="changePw" href="#">
  <i class="fa">Icon</i> Change Password
</a>
```

(don't forget to test this in a window of less than 700px width)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove it with CSS, you will need to use javascript / jQuery like so:

```
$('a').mouseover(function(e){
    if($(window).width() > 700){
        $('a').removeAttr("title");
    }
    else{
        $('a').attr("title", "Title");
    }
});
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wg8vjza3/).

This is a quick/dirty solution and i don't think this is great for SEO.

The (IMO) correct way would be to always have the title tag, on desktop and mobile.

EDIT: Spelling